# What does "looked every day of it" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> She was in her late fifties and **looked every day of it**.

In this instance, what does *looked every day of it* mean?

Comment: ... it means she looked like she was 50... or maybe even older.

Comment: like a feeble old woman
......................................

Answer (score 2):

In the example you provided it means that she really looked her age. It's a stylistic way of saying that she absolutely did not look any younger than what she was.

For example:

> She was 55 and looked every day of it.

The woman could look 55 or older, but certainly not younger.